# How to fix the occurrence of random numbers

Tags: matlab, random

I have the following code:

```
Accuracy=off(data,z)
for i=1:100
    n = size(data,1);
    data_rand = data(randperm(n),:);
    m = ceil(n/20);
    k = 1:m:n-m;
    test = data_rand(k:k+m-1,:);
    train = [data_rand(1:k-1,:); data_rand(k+m:end,:)];
    %/  code to calculate auc
end
accuracy=mean(auc)
```

Every iteration the values of `train` and `test` are changed, so the value of `auc` is changed every time.

Say the final result is `accuracy=0.7654` and another time `accuracy=0.6543` or `accuracy=0.4657`. I want to fixed a specific result, say `0.6543`, i.e if I run previous code more times I want to obtain the same result (`0.6543`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the Random Number Generator (RNG). Fix this by setting [`rng('default')`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) as first line after the declaration of the `for` loop. This forces the RNG to always start at the same point.

The `seed` can be chosen simply:

```
seed = 4; %// starts the seed at 4
rng(seed);
```

You can play with the number of the seed to find which number results in a satisfying permutation for you.

Comment: but in some data sets it gives bad result

Comment: @AsmaaDaoud You can play with the `seed` of the rng (see the linked documentation) to generate a starting point, but otherwise you can't fix this through the RNG.  What you can do however is `randperm` your data until you have a satisfying set, save that one before the loop and keep using that.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to use seed

Comment: @AsmaaDaoud you could of course click on the documentation link I provided in my question and read the page, which includes examples on all its uses.